# I have a CSS specificity

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

[This is my html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u47ZS.png)

[This is my css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfSCL.png)

When in CSS I write the CSS code for .keys class like this and add class .transistionOfKeys to html then my border properties does not add to it

But when I change my CSS code to this by removing .container and just keeping it to .keys then it works

[after changing CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjxdR.png)

So I want to know reason for this...

Hope someone answer this question soon...

Comment: Please include your code in your question as text, not links. It makes it easier for us to copy it into our own IDEs to test it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the selector for the second rule to `.container .transistionOfKeys {...}` to achieve the same [CSS specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) as the first CSS rule.

Comment: I’ve linked to the MDN page for an explanation of specificity.